# canDeactivate guard breaks routing history in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, onbeforeunload, candeactivate

I am trying to implement canDeactivate guard for unsaved edit. And when I am testing, it seems that route history is getting broken. I know solution is there in angular but it is post v 12 and currently I am working on a project in angular 8. And I am not able to find solution for the same.

Here is my code :

guard :

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate() ?
      true :
      confirm('WARNING: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back and save these changes, or OK to lose these changes.');
  }
}
```

Component :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return !this.isDataUpdated();
  }
```

routing :

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ListViewTableComponent, pathMatch: 'full',canDeactivate:[PendingChangesGuard] }];
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: route is getting added in history and when we are actually clicking on back button or next button than that time we are getting the same link for the time we have got the alert box. @Drenai